# Why is `Array(3).map(k=>5)` empty, but `Array(3).fill(null).map(k=>5)` works?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm using this design pattern analogously to C++'s [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve):

```
> Array(3).map(k=>5)
[ <3 empty items> ]
> Array(3).fill(null).map(k=>5)
[ 5, 5, 5 ]
```

Clearly it's not a bug, as same functionality in Node.JS, Chrome and Firefox. But why does it act like this?

Comment: _"`map` calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. **callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values**..."_

Comment: Hmm, so here 'assigned values' includes assignment to `undefined`? - E.g.: this works also: `Array(3).fill(undefined).map(k=>5)`

Comment: @AT Yes. I've should have posted the complete sentence... :( The missing part is: _"..., **including `undefined`**. It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value)."_ ([`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

Comment: `Array(3)` creates an object of type array with length 3, but there are no items available in that array so you can iterate over the array using its length with a loop but `map` iterates over the items of an array which in this case it has none.

Comment: btw, `null` !== `undefined`.

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah I know, that's why I posted it as something I was surprised that worked, whereas `null` came to no surprise. @Andreas: Hmm, strange. Well thanks for clearing this up!